# Как прибить footer?

Tags: css

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 7 % ;
    background: #36638e;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 783px;
    height: 40;
    padding - top: 3px;
    bottom: 0 % ;
    border - radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

А то на динамических страницах, на которых появляется полоса прокрутки, то футер просто остается внизу, допустим я прокручу его вниз, и все он остается по центру страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ8pd/

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ8pd/2/

Comment: Нет, не удалось мне сделать его так как вы в этом исходнике написали...

Comment: родителю необходимо задать position: relative

Comment: Получилось, извините что сделал поспешные выводы. Вот только думаю как под себя подстроить и вернуть былую красоту)